# Unable to build a gtkmm program that uses std::make_unique

Tags: c++, c++14, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I have been programming using Gtkmm for a while now, using C++11 features without problems. Today, I added a line of code using the C++14 feature `std::make_unique` and got a compiler error. At first, I thought I had an issue with my build configuration but after some testing, I narrowed it down to Gtkmm. Here is code that builds fine on my system:

Build command:

```
g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp
```

Code:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> intPtr;
    intPtr = std::make_unique<int>(3);

    return 0;
}
```

If I switch to this build command:

```
g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

The code no longer builds. I get the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:14: error: ‘make_unique’ is not a member of ‘std’
     intPtr = std::make_unique<int>(3);
              ^
main.cpp:7:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     intPtr = std::make_unique<int>(3);
```

What's the problem with Gtkmm? For your information, I am using g++ v 5.4.0 and gtkmm 3.0.

EDIT: It seems this is not C++14 related. I tried building with other C++14 features, like `[[DEPRECATED]]` and it worked fine. Maybe only the standard library... I also tried switching to g++ 7 and got the same errors.

Comment: BTW, how about `auto intPtr = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(3));` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into a problem with the C++ standard that is specified by the `--cflags` argument in `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --lib`.  If `-std=c++11` or something older is the result of providing the `--cflags` option, then it will override any earlier specifications.  You can probably fix the problem just by placing your desired specification at the end:

```
g++ main.cpp `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` -std=c++14
```

Comment: You are right that the `--cflags` argument in `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --lib` uses something older that `-std=c++14`. I expanded it and it uses the `-std=c++11` flag, which is probably why it does not work. Your updated command, however, yields the same error for me (even if I switch to g++7).